# HTTP Proxy server in C++

Tags: c++, http, proxy, https

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTP/S proxy starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017952/http-s-proxy-starting-point)

I need to build a HTTP proxy server with custom features, but I can't spend much time coding it from scratch, so I'm looking for a simple open-source lightweight proxy server with a easy-understable source code that I can modify it to meet my requirements. It should work with SSL and gzip.

Does anyone know a project about a proxy server like that?

Comment: Did you search on [google](http://www.google.co.in/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=http+proxy+server+%2B+c%2B%2B#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=http+proxy+server+%2B+c%2B%2B+&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=aa1b0f39a4714da7&biw=1278&bih=739)? or you are expecting us to do the searching for you? Check the link a simple search throws a number of results..

Comment: @Als: Sure. What I expect is that people that know a proxy server like that help me and people that don't know anyone ignore the question. I am been searching it for hours without luck. I'll see the ones you suggested.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017952/http-s-proxy-starting-point

Comment: The link in my comment is a simple search and it yields a number of results, ofcourse you will need to see which one suits you. If you already searched and didn't find anything useful please mention that in the question itself, your Q should atleast reflect what all you have tried to resolve your problem, In my experience if your Q shows efforts you have put in to resolve the issues, peeps are more inclined to help you out.

Comment: You could look at https://github.com/stevealbertwong/proxy! I also written an accompanying blog post: https://stevealbertwong.github.io/2017/01/20/multiprocess-proxy/
It also has caching, blacklist, http-request response header parsing and multiprocessing features. Currently I am working on adding threadpool feature

Answer (score 1):

Tinyproxy http://banu.com/tinyproxy/ may be what you are looking for. It has a tiny code base, and according to the website, HTTPS is supported. I also believe that gzip is not a problem.