# How to retrieve text that will be written on web browsers by VC++?

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, text, mfc

I'm trying to retrieve text that will be written on web browsers(e.g. IE, Chrome..).
I want to know the best way to do this. I do not limit browser type.

Comment: Is this a client side program or something running on a web server? If you want to do it on the client, you'll need to implement a web proxy, not a trivial operation. If you're doing this on the server, you need to be more specific about how your existing code is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're doing this on a workstation, and what you want to do is trace the code that goes back and forth between a server and a browser on your workstation, the best way is probably to implement a proxy, or to attach to a proxy server that's capable of logging a connection.

Rather than try to teach you how to write a proxy server, I'll point you to an existing question: [C++ HTTP Proxy Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017952/http-s-proxy-starting-point)

Comment: No it isn't. I simply asked that I want to retrieve 'text' that written on a page.

Comment: You need to be more specific... where is this code running? The server? The workstation? Without more details, it's impossible to provide a better answer.

Comment: I simply said that can I retrieve text from browsers. this is not environment specific.